# Laravel: Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY (Querying a Many-to-Many relationship)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I got a project with the Models Menu and User, which are in a Many-to-Many relationship.

On one site I show the past menus per calender week, on the other I want to show the order history of a specific user per calender week.

I got the menu history working with the following query:

```
public static function archives()
    {
        return  Menu::selectRaw('week(date, 1) as kw, year(date) as year')
                ->orderByRaw('min(date) asc')
                ->groupBy('kw', 'year')
                ->get();
    }
```

Now i thought about the same query for the User, but I get errors that are not even in my statement.

```
public static function archives(int $id)
    {
        return User::find($id)->menus()
                    ->selectRaw('week(date, 1) as kw, year(date) as year')
                    ->orderByRaw('min(date) asc')
                    ->groupBy('kw', 'year')
                    ->get();

    }
```

Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mysql is set to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option.

> If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by
>   default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING
>   condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are
>   neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on
>   them

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

However in laravel you can overwrite it in `config/database.php` connections array `mysql` strict mode

```
'mysql' => [
            ...
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Comment: what do you have settings in `config/database.php` for mysql connection `strict` ?

Comment: Yes I have, it was on default. It works without it. What does it do excactly?